# What does "%1$d" mean in a format string?

Tags: java, formatting

I can't figure out what this `%1$d` format specifier means. Can someone help me?

```
int zahl = 100;
System.out.format("A number: %1$d %n", zahl);
```

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax _"'d'  integral  The result is formatted as a decimal integer "_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1$ represents your first argument which is your zahl variable. %d is the format specifier for integer. The $ convention is used to avoid multiple times your argument is being reused. One example is,

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.printf("hours %tH: minutes %tM: seconds %tS%n", date, date, date);
```

In the above print statement instead of passing your date variable multiple number of times, you can achieve it instead in the following way,

```
System.out.printf("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$tp %1$tL %1$tN %1$tz %n", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

`x$` means arguments number `x`.

The following will print `Hello World`:

```java
System.out.printf("%s %s", "Hello", "World");
```

Both below will print `World Hello`:

```java
System.out.printf("%2$s %1$s", "Hello", "World");
System.out.printf("%s %s", "World", "Hello");
```

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax:

> The format specifiers for general, character, and numerical types have the following syntax:
> `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`